# Properly granting restrictive administrative privileges to developers on a production server

Tags: linux, account-security, permissions, sudo

I am a business owner with a strong technical background, say a programmer, though not an advanced system administrator. I've bought a VPS server where I want to host several applications and webpages. One of the apps consists of a back end, admin front end, and user front end. Another one is just back end and front end. So 5 different programmers develop those apps. From time to time, as the development takes place, those programmers need to install and upgrade some packages, modify system configs and so on, i.e. they need ssh access and some root privileges.

And here is the tricky part. It is obvious that I don't want them to see and gain access to the folders they are not supposed to see, i.e. the devs of the first app shouldn't have access to the folders of the second app and vice versa. Moreover, the backend dev of the first app shouldn't have access to the frontend folders of the same app and the same goes for the second app. Also, I would like to restrict access for them to certain commands like `visudo` or `reboot`, so they wouldn't be able to lock me out of my own server or reboot it without my consent.

Now, if I give them sudo privileges for them to be able to run administrative tasks needed for their development, then they have access to everything and it becomes practically impossible to restrict access for them to certain folders and commands. On the other hand, if I 8don't8 give them sudo privileges, then it becomes a huge pain for me to every time to install packages and give them access to certain files and commands they need to continue development. There are over 1500 commands and the corresponding number of system files in Linux they could potentially need access to, so it's very *very* inconvenient for me to spend so much time to administer the VPS, especially since I'm not a very advanced system administrator and I don't have much time because I need to run my business.

There are already numerous posts and threads on the Internet where people try to find solutions to somewhat related problems, like these:
[One](https://superuser.com/questions/149404/create-an-ssh-user-who-only-has-permission-to-access-specific-folders), [Two](https://superuser.com/questions/299036/can-i-create-an-ssh-user-which-can-access-only-certain-directory?rq=1), [Three](https://superuser.com/questions/969292/restrict-access-to-directory-with-sudo), [Four](https://superuser.com/questions/893632/deny-access-to-a-specific-folder-for-a-sudo-user), [Five](https://serverfault.com/questions/36759/editing-sudoers-file-to-restrict-a-users-commands), [Six](https://serverfault.com/questions/308198/how-to-disable-sudoer-from-editing-etc-sudoers-file), [Seven](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419330/can-i-restrict-a-user-with-root-privilegeswith-sudo-from-accessing-deleting-a), [Eight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79147/protect-folder-from-sudoers), [Nine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282459/prevent-sudo-user-access-to-specific-folder-and-files),
and they still have no reasonable solutions to them, only those that involve some super-complex activities and not giving the desired result.

So from my point of view as a business owner, it should be something like this: there is a root user who can do everything. Root can create admins and define access rights for them, for example in that very sudoers file. Then it's root's decision whether to give access to an admin to the sudoers file itself and any of the folders and commands of root's choice. For example, an admin could be able to run any command in the system except `reboot` and `visudo` and the admin can access all files and folders except `/etc/sudoers` and say `/var/www/private_folder` even *with* sudo privileges invoked (meaning the admin can't even copy those files, overwrite them, `chmod` and `chown` them and so on, i.e. access them with any command).

That would immediately make the whole system administration *a lot* easier and logical, eliminating the need for complex solutions like chroot jails, separate bash environments, splitting servers into virtual machines, using containers and so on. And it's so simple, a matter of a couple of conditions in the code, if I understand it correctly from a developer's perspective. Also, I want to be in control of my VPS, not having to trust any other third person believing he/she won't steal my information and/or destroy my whole system either by making a mistake or intentionally and basically it can be considered as a serious security vulnerability from a certain point of view.

This seems so obvious and logical for me, that I was really discouraged and embarrassed that it's really isn't like that in Linux. Maybe 20 years ago when Linux was created it was enough to have only a root and sudoers and the rest of users to accomplish tasks they had at that time, but today everything goes a bit different way already and that archaic approach is not usable anymore.

Of course I realize I might be understanding something incorrectly and there is a strong reason why it has to be as it is. If so, then please let me know why is it so and what is a correct and easy way of solving my problem described above without a need to build a behemoth on my VPS or manually administering it all the time by myself. After all, it should be user-friendly, right? Now it's not.

Comment: What happens if the developers of one app need to upgrade a package, and that breaks one of the other applications?  To me this is more of an architecture problem than a security/usability problem.

Comment: Good point @Xander but this is exactly the thing that I'm responsible for as an owner of the system. I could easily accept this behaviour realizing it could potentially break something. My solution to this would be to test it on a test server, then if it's okay apply it to the production server. But that should be up to me, not the designer of the OS. Besides it's anyway like this nowadays. You have no guarantee that your code will work flawlessly after a next package or system update, so anyway such things have to be tested in test environments, right?

Comment: But this is why we have solutions like virtualization and containerization; to solve this problem.  I don't necessarily agree that the fact that you don't want to use them means that this is a problem the core OS should solve as well.

Comment: If you need to give developers root access, and don't want them accessing other apps, then put the other apps on other systems.  There are fine-grained access control systems like PowerBroker but where your requirement is "must be able to alter arbitrary config files" your base requirement will break the security of the systems available to control it.  (This would be just as true on Windows as it is on Linux, by the way.)

Comment: Also please understand that I'm not simply trying to be contrarian. It's just that based on my experience, I think the desired architecture (with or without the changes you propose) is an anti-pattern.  I've seen it used in practice many times, and repeatedly seen it cause pain and heartache and problems that are difficult to find and fix.

Comment: Yes, but why we would even need those solutions if it could be solved in a much more straightforward and logical way? It's always better to make systems more simple, not more complex, as complexity imposes systems to faults and security breaches. And I don't see any practical reason why it should really be as it is at the moment. Do you see such reasons? Can you explain it to me? @Xander

Comment: I'll not write an answer because I'm not sure exactly what the question is. Systems like SELinux enable the kind of role based access controls you're discussing. But it's a pain to setup and use. Typical solutions to this problem involve using multiple hosts for the various environments and modules of the product - dev/prod, frontend/backend/housekeeping, etc. I understand your pain, but on the other hand, is it that Linux is the limitation or just your perspective of what should be?

Comment: Ok, @gowenfawr what should I do with the backend and frontend parts of an application? Should I also split them onto different servers or virtual machines? Don't you agree it's a waste of system resources to make it like that?

Comment: @artteq: *"Yes, but why we would even need those solutions if it could be solved in a much more straightforward and logical way?"* - your proposal of an pseudo-admin being able to do everything but ... is insecure given that a programmer might write its own software and run it and thus essentially do everything. Stronger separation as proposed with containers is actually easier to keep secure and more logical (one clear border instead of granular access rights which might give too few or too much), no matter if you like it or not.

Comment: @artteq maybe not different machines or VMs, but containers can be very lightweight

Comment: If you expect 2+ groups of developers to have access to the backend and frontend, and you don't trust them with all apps, then yes, they should be split.  I don't agree it's a waste of resources, although I question your premise.  Among other things, you shouldn't have developers on a live operational system to begin with.

Comment: Hi @Pedro well I just think that many of such issues could be solved much easier than involving virtualization and containerization, but it would need to change the basic approach a little bit which today became archaic already. And it happened historically like that, not for any specific reasonable reason. So maybe it's time to re-think the way it should work?

Comment: I renamed your title to make it less click-bait-y and more about the core of the problem. Feel free to edit if it doesn't fit.

Comment: Reading your email and going through the issues you're facing, I don't think you're being unreasonable. I suppose the reason that it hasn't changed is that 1) teams adapt to existing environments making the best of what they have and 2) some of the changes you're discussing would involve changing pretty fundamental concepts, which would totally change what the systems look like. Or even 3) because the amount of work and maintenance to implement these things is probably more than just finding a way around.

Comment: Have a look at SELinux, it's been around for decades, yet why is it not common place in all linux distros today?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, of course not, if you can restrict sudoers file to be accessible by only you as its owner, then no other user or program will be able to access it. Consequently you can secure any other folder or command in your system and all external threats become a matter of your application security, not the system it's installed on. Now it's different, you can restrict access to the sudoers file only by NOT giving sudo permissions, and that creates a problem I've described in the post when you have to continually administer your system. Am I not right?

Comment: "it should be user-friendly, right" -- who said? And you might also consider that you have a unique use case for which Linux is not designed. ***Could*** we redesign the entire permissions structure to suit this level of hierarchical flexibility? Sure. But that would make the underlying OS more complex, which is a bigger risk than making your app more complex in your application of the controls you desire.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, and you have a lot of expectations of the system that are not reasonable and should be replaced with the design patterns that have been in place to solve this problem. "But why can't it be different?" is not answerable. It things were different then it could be different. "But I see a problem!" Sure, but the cure is worse than the disease.

Answer (score 3):

Use containers, or virtual machines. Docker and KVM aren't that difficult to learn (but are not trivial either), takes time to properly manage, but will be way easier than the nightmare you are entering head-first into.

Developers usually don't have administration backend, or mindset. Making a mess of libraries and config files are easy to do, reverting the mess isn't trivial.

You will want a reliable environment, and a container/VM helps immensely. Something went wrong? Delete the current deployment and re-deploy the previous version. Developer messed up everything and destroyed the environment? No big deal, deploy the previous version. Developer ran `chown -R dev:dev /` on the host? Good luck rebuilding everything.

There are technologies out there to confine people on their places, but it usually don't scale, are terrible to manage, and cumbersome to use. A container is easy to start, easy to kill, and keeps everyone on their containers. Or a VM: ClearLinux have lightweight VMs and they are awesome, super light and super fast.